# How to disable prompt auto clear in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, 22.04, configuration, tty

When starting Ubuntu in Hyper-V VM, (See **picture 1**), Ubuntu will auto clear the `test login:` prompt text at around 22 seconds. (See **picture 2**)

Now press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to make the prompt text appear again. (See **picture 3**)

[image]

How to make Ubuntu not to auto clear the prompt text on console?

**Update:**

This also cause the following problem: When you login very quickly, within just 1 second, and then type some text on the tty console:

```
root@test:~# bar
root@test:~# hello ubuntu
```

Now wait around 22 - 1 = 21 seconds, Ubuntu will auto clear the `root@test:~# hello ubuntu`:

```
root@test:~# bar
```

Now you have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to make the prompt appear again.

Comment: see `man agetty`

Comment: I tried to run "`agetty --noclear`" on the console but get this error "`agetty: not enough arguments`". How to make this config auto apply to system reboot?

Comment: `agetty` is started by your init-system. I guess it is systemd. Use this as a starting point: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/getty

Comment: I have tried to set `TTYVTDisallocate=no` according to that link, the TTYVTDisallocate=no` makes it "worse screen (`keep all service start status messages`) + prompt also cleared" , I think it may not relate to `--noclear` or `TTYVTDisallocate=no`.